# How to use the search feature in PDFObject?

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, pdfobject

I'm using [PDFObject](http://pdfobject.com) to try to search a PDF for a certain term and highlight it. The website actually [generates code for such an application automatically](http://pdfobject.com/generator.php) but for some reason this code isn't actually searching my PDF at all, nor is it highlighting the word I want to highlight... does anyone know how I can do this or rectify my code?

Here is the code that the website auto generates for me (in HTML):

```
    <!-- insert in the document body -->

<object data='sample#search=location&highlight=20,20,20,20' 
        type='application/pdf' 
        width='100%' 
        height='100%'>

<p>It appears your Web browser is not configured to display PDF files. 
No worries, just <a href='sample'>click here to download the PDF file.</a></p>

</object>
```

The search term I want to find (and have highlighted) in my PDF Object is a word called 'location'.

I've copied this code into my overall HTML code, which is as follows:

```
    <html>
    <head>
     <title>PDFObject Example</title>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="pdfobject.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript">
      window.onload = function (){
        var myPDF = new PDFObject({ url: "sample.pdf" }).embed();
      };
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
      <object data='sample.pdf#search=location&highlight=20,20,20,20' 
              type='application/pdf' 
              width='100%' 
              height='100%'>

      <p>It appears your Web browser is not configured to display PDF files. 
      No worries, just <a href='sample.pdf'>click here to download the PDF file.</a></p>
</body>
      </object>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance!

---

**UPDATE** (7/13)

The code provided by Pipwerks works perfectly, thank you. I just have one remaining question; I used 'this' code (see below) to add a highlight for a search term, but the highlighting itself does NOT automatically show up when I search for a term; any idea how to resolve that? So essentially, when the PDF opens in Acrobat, the search function is working fine, and in the left menu pane, I can see the results of the search; however the terms I am searching for themselves are not automatically highlighted on the screen upon the PDF loading; is there anyway to set this up so that the terms I'm searching for are highlighted upon loading the PDF?

```
 <html>
  <head>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="pdfobject.js"></script>
     <script type='text/javascript'>

       function embedPDF(){

         var myPDF = new PDFObject({ 

           url: 'sample.pdf',
           pdfOpenParams: { search: 'B27-1', highlight: '30,30,30,10' }

         }).embed();  

       }

       window.onload = embedPDF; //Feel free to replace window.onload if needed.

     </script>
  </head>
      </object>
</html>
```

[HERE](http://postimg.org/image/qav3cn4gv/) is what the PDF currently looks like when index.html (the search feature works correctly, but my term isn't highlighted by default).

[HERE](http://s2.postimg.org/v4pukf555/Screen_Shot_2015_07_13_at_6_56_59_PM.png) is what I want the PDF to look like upon loading index.html; if you actually click the search term, then a highlight box appears (as seen in the image). I would like for that highlight box to load with the PDF for whatever search term I am trying to find on my map.

Any help would be appreciated, you've really been a lifesaver Pipwerks, thanks for your help!

Comment: Were you able to find any PDF reader which actually does the highlighting you wanted? I have basically the same problem you have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the [PDF Open Parameters](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_open_parameters.pdf) are Adobe-specific and don't work in most PDF readers, including the built-in PDF viewers in Chrome and Firefox. In fact, it's been [an issue/feature request in Google's Chromium project](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=64309) for nearly five years.

Does it work for you in Adobe Reader?

#### -- UPDATE --

Re-reading your post, your code is not correct. You have mixed up the static and JavaScript options -- you need to pick one or the other. As you have written it, your JavaScript (which doesn't include search params) is overwriting your HTML version.

JavaScript method:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>PDFObject Example</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="pdfobject.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>

function embedPDF(){

  var myPDF = new PDFObject({ 

    url: 'sample.pdf',
    pdfOpenParams: { search: 'location' }

  }).embed();  

}

window.onload = embedPDF;

</script></head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Static HTML method:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>PDFObject Example</title>
</head>
<body>
<object data='sample.pdf#search=location' 
        type='application/pdf' 
        width='100%' 
        height='100%'>

  <p>It appears your Web browser is not configured to display PDF files. 
  No worries, just <a href='sample.pdf'>click here to download the PDF file.</a></p>

</object>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is the code I've written (and copied from the Code Generator) correct? Should it work assuming I use Adobe Reader? 

And how can I run this code in Adobe Reader? The way I've been testing the code (in general) is by writing out the HTML in a text document, and then opening the code in my browser (Safari or alternatively I.E.); in this manner, I'm always forced to use the built-in PDF viewer for whatever browser I'm using. How could this be tested in Adobe Reader? Thank you Philip.

Comment: I ran the code that I originally posted in Firefox (specifically the Adobe Acrobat reader plug-in) and I still don't see the search term I want highlighted... any suggestions? (I disabled all plug-ins on Firefox with the exception of 'Adobe Acrobat' [Adobe PDF Plug-In for Firefox]). The PDF loads fine, but I just can't get the search term to be highlighted. In case it's relevant, the only things in my folder are the PDF (called sample.pdf), an index.html file (the file I'm running), and the pdfobject.js file.

Comment: *update* I tried running the HTML in Adobe Reader XI (I right-clicked on the file and then tried to 'open with' Adobe Reader , but the Adobe Reader says that an HTML is not a supported file type. Any help and/or suggestions would greatly be appreciated. Essentially my goal is to create some code that can search a PDF map file for specific room numbers.

Comment: Update 7/13; the code you provided me with is working perfectly; thank you for the help. I have one remaining question; how do I get the highlighting function to actually highlight the words I've searched for upon the PDF loading? Right now that is not currently occurring...I've re-worded this question above to make it more clear.

Comment: Glad you got it working. RE: highlighting terms, that's beyond the scope of PDFObject, it's up to the PDF reader. Most of them don't support PDF Open Parameters, so it's hit and miss.

Comment: Are you aware of any PDF readers that would be able to specifically support the highlighting feature? Right now I've been using Adobe Reader DC on Safari, and while the search function works properly, the highlighting does not show up automatically (upon the PDF loading). I'm looking for a PDF reader for I.E. if you do have any suggestions.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't kept track of them for a while.

Comment: Support for search and highlighting will vary greatly from browser to browser and platform to platform. There's no standard feature set or API for PDF renderers. The only way to ensure everyone gets the same experience and feature set would be to use a system like PDF.js to render the PDF, bypassing the native browser/OS PDF rendering.